# Binomial expansion of $(1+x)^{2n}$ and proof that $\binom{2n}{n} = \binom{n}{0}^2 + \binom{n}{1}^2 + \binom{n}{2}^2 + ... + \binom{n}{n}^2$

Tags: binomial-coefficients, generating-functions, binomial-theorem

**By considering the coefficient of $x^n$ in the expansion of $(1+x)^{2n}$, show that $\binom{2n}{n} = \binom{n}{0}^2 + \binom{n}{1}^2 + \binom{n}{2}^2 + ... + \binom{n}{n}^2$.**

*Note: You might find it helpful to use $(1+x)^{2n} = (1+x)^n(1+x)^n$ and that $\binom{n}{n-r} = \binom{n}{r}$.*

I have considered expanding it with $(1+x)^{2n} = (1+x)^n(1+x)^n$, however, after expansion I don't know how to approach it.

In addition, I've tried expanding it as follows:
$$(1+x)^{2n} = \binom{2n}{0} + \binom{2n}{1}x + \binom{2n}{2}x^2 +...+ \binom{2n}{n}x^n + ... + \binom{2n}{2n}x^{2n}$$
but I don't know how to approach it as well.

Comment: In a product of two polynomials, what is the formula for one coefficient of the product in terms of the coefficients of the factors?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We have 
$$(1+x)^n(1+x)^n=\left({{n}\choose{0}} + {{n}\choose{1}}x+\ldots+{{n}\choose{n}}x^n \right)\left({{n}\choose{0}} + {{n}\choose{1}}x+\ldots+{{n}\choose{n}}x^n \right)$$
The $x^n$ term in this expansion is
$$\sum_{k=0}^n{n\choose k}x^k\cdot{n\choose n-k}x^{n-k}=\sum_{k=0}^n{n\choose k}^2x^n$$

Comment: Thanks. How would you go about proving the second part of the question?

Comment: From what you've already done, you know that the coefficient of $x^n$ is ${2n \choose n}$, so we must have ${2n\choose n}=\sum_{k=0}^n{n\choose k}^2$.